# Is it standard C++ to call move() with an output iterator that has been moved previously?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, c++11, move-semantics

While brushing up on algorithm design and learning C++11 at the same time, I came up with the following implementation for heap sort:

> ```
> template <typename It, typename Comp>
> void heapSort(It begin, It end, Comp compFunc, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
> {
>     std::make_heap(begin, end, compFunc);
>     std::sort_heap(begin, end, compFunc);
> }
>
> template <typename It, typename Comp, typename IterCat>
> void heapSort(It begin, It end, Comp compFunc, IterCat)
> {
>     typedef typename It::value_type value_type;
>
>     std::vector<value_type> randomAccessContainer;
>     randomAccessContainer.reserve(std::distance(begin, end));
>     std::move(begin, end, std::back_inserter(randomAccessContainer));
>
>     heapSort(std::begin(randomAccessContainer), std::end(randomAccessContainer), compFunc, std::random_access_iterator_tag());
>     std::move(std::begin(randomAccessContainer), std::end(randomAccessContainer), begin);
> }
> ```

Is it standard C++ to first move from `[begin, end)` into a new container, and then move from that container back into `[begin, end)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it standard C++ to first move from [begin, end) into a new container, and then move from that container back into [begin, end)?

I was initially confused by your use of the word "*standard*", and edited the question so that it was asking whether this was "*legal*". The answer to that question would be: "**Yes**, *it is perfectly legal*". After the elements in the original range are moved from, they are still in a valid (even though unspecified) state.

Hence, the second call to `std::move()` will just move-assign elements, and the type of those elements shall have a move-assignment operator without pre-conditions. As long as this is the case, I see no problem with that.

After editing your question, though, I started to wonder whether you actually wanted to ask if this is "standard", meaning "common practice", which is why I restored the original wording.

The answer to this question is "**Partly**". You would normally initialize your temporary vector by using a couple of *move iterators* rather than invoking `std::move`:

```
std::vector<value_type> randomAccessContainer(
    std::make_move_iterator(begin),
    std::make_move_iterator(end)
    );
```

Apart from this, your implementation seems correct to me.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Oops. Right. I totally deleted that from my brain when I got to the end of the answer. Thank you for pointing out

Comment: I suppose I meant to ask both questions. I've accepted your answer for making it clear it's preferable to use make_move_iterator but there isn't anything incorrect about the concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't.

I can see how you'd need it to be a random access container if it wasn't already. In that case prefer `std::make_move_iterator`:

```
std::vector<value_type> randomAccessContainer(
     std::make_move_iterator(begin), 
     std::make_move_iterator(end));
```

In all other cases, you'd want to be sorting in-place. (Unless you need "no effects" on exception, maybe)